# Is there a way to modify the brightness of LEDs in rpi-ws281x-go library after calling MakeWS2811()?

Tags: c, go, raspberry-pi3, led

I've been playing with a Raspberry Pi and Golang to animate some WS2812 LEDs. I've been using the rpi-ws281x-go (https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-go) library which is a Go wrapper around a C library (https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x). I'm not extremely familiar with C let alone Go wrappers of C libraries.

I can see that in the C code, I can access and change the brightness of the LEDs which is applied every time the render function is called. However, in the Go wrapper library, I don't see a way to access that variable. I can see that when I call ws2811.MakeWS2811(&opt), I can set the brightness in the opt struct. How can I change that brightness after calling MakeWS2811()?

I know how to apply my own brightness in my own animation functions in Go, but that seems redundant since the C function is going to do the same thing.

Comment: Better to post example code fragments than to reference external resources.  I am no Go expert (i.e. zero knowledge) so cannot really post an answer,  but looking at some of the example Go code for this library, it seems to me at a guess that because `MakeWS2811()` takes a _pointer_ to the `opt` structure, you may simply be able to change the `opt.Channels[n].Brightness` and then render.  That is when you render, it uses the current state of the `opt` not the state it was when `MakeWS2811()` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Clifford [MakeWS2811(...)](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-go/blob/d1c4b49fa01da378f9c24e72a1cf042795dc5a44/ws2811_arm.go#L58) does take a pointer, but it looks like it makes a copy of the options in C.

However the returned instance has a [Leds(nChannel)](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-go/blob/d1c4b49fa01da378f9c24e72a1cf042795dc5a44/ws2811.go#L135) method, giving direct access to set the colours of LEDs. You can reduce the colour value to reduce the brightness (approximately).

```
...
opt.Channels[0].Brightness = ... original value 0 to 255
ws, err := MakeWS2811(&opts)
...

ws.Leds(0)[0] = 0xff //bright red
ws.Leds(0)[1] = 0x7f //half as bright
ws.Render()
```

Note each time the C lib renders, it still [scales](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/5b73b22517040423a657cc5e245529a9ed90d4d6/ws2811.c#L1140) the colours you set by the original brightness.

Comment: I knew that each time the C lib renders, it scales. I was trying to get around doing it in my code by controlling that scaling value. Guess it can't. Thanks for taking a look at it. I'll just have to scale it in my code.

Comment: Ah yes you mentioned in the question you already knew how to do it in your code. I think the original author might appreciate you submitting your change to the library as a PR.